# Old program prints blank pages in CUPS

Tags: printing

I've set up cups-pdf and it works well.

The problem is when I use an old program designed to print to an Epson dot matrix printer that it gives me blank pages. I asked the program to print to a file and found that the report seems to include some special characters. I am attaching an image of the report for clarification.

[image: Printer outut]

On this image, you can see the report as viewed from the Text Editor. The curious thing is that if I print this file from the Text Editor to CUPS, the report comes out fine.

If I run a command like this on the output file

```
cat test | sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' | lpr -P PDF
```

cups-pdf works well but the format of the report gets compromised and I can't make the program run such a script.

I checked if this was an encoding problem so I ran

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 test | >test5
```

and in this case, I got a blank page in the output file.

I also modified the maker and model of the printer in the CUPS localhost without success.

My conclusion is that CUPS could be running a filter that's causing the blank pages.

My question is what changes do I need to make to the CUPS configuration to be able to print from this old program?

I need to use CUPS because in the next phase I want the program to print directly to a network printer.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS 64bits